# how to solve reportMissingImports problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I see this message in problems tab when importing my modules into vs-code-jupyter notebook:
'Import "models.constants" could not be resolved'

However, When I run the cell it runs successfully without any error.Besides the problem is not shown for installed packages such as numpy or pandas. I added my project's URL to environment variables and also add some lines of codes to setting.JSON file suggested by other similar posts, but the problem still exists.The problem does not exist for .py file though. How can I solve this issue?
Here I included the added lines and an image of my problem:

```
  "python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true,
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./AIInvestmentProject/models","./AIInvestmentProject"],
  "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
```

[image]

Comment: look https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3035

Comment: @Andrey Zet Including "python.pylanceLspNotebooksEnabled": false in user settings.json did not worked for me. I hope Pylance team work on this problem and fix this incompatibility between Jupiter and Pylance. Until that time I disabled Pylance extension and for now the error disappeared.